# validate method not called django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to test **validate** **method** on modelSerializer but it is **NOT CALLED**.

Why is not working ? Have i been missed something ? the same scenario works at different project

at urls

```
urlpatterns = [ path('api/allposts/', allposts, name='allposts') ]
```

at views:

```
from .serializer import PostSerializer
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from .models import Post
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

def allposts(request):
    qs = Post.objects.all()[:3]
    ser = PostSerializer(qs, many=True)
    data = JSONRenderer().render(ser.data)
    return JsonResponse(json.loads(data), safe=False)
```

at models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
         return self.title
```

at serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'poster', 'url']

    def validate(self, data):
        if 'facebook' in data.get('url'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('you can not add facebook')
        return data
```

Comment: serializer's validate method is called when you call serializer.is_valid(). Since you are serializing db instances you are not required to call is_valid(), hence validate() method is not called

Comment: @Vikramark  yes, I got it , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

serializer's validate method is called when you call `serializer.is_valid()`. Since you are serializing db instances you are not required to call `is_valid()`, hence `validate()` method is not called